# Move the PC into another register with xtensa (lx6) cores

Tags: assembly, program-counter, position-independent-code, xtensa

I'm trying to get the current PC value into an assembly routine written for xtensa (lx6) cores. After digging into the instruction set doc, I cannot see really how to achieve this. It looks as if the PC is not mapped into the 16 AR, and I cannot see it listed into the registers I can access through the RSR instruction, or even the RER instruction.

Any advice ?

Comment: What are your restrictions? You can normally use the assembler and linker to access a static address, e.g. `.` or `$`.

Comment: I would like to get the current PC value, not the address that has been linked.
I've made a few attempts :
mov a2,PC
rsr a2,PC
rer a2,PC
all have failed, PC being a "bad register name".

Comment: There is the usual trick of calling the next instruction then you get the return address in `a0`.

Comment: If there isn't a special PC-relative address-generation instruction (like x86-64 LEA or RISC-V aiupc), abusing an instruction intended for function calls normally works, like Jester suggested.  Either call a helper function that returns its return address, or call next-instruction if that doesn't break return-address prediction (mismatched call/ret).  Most ISAs have something like this as an option to read the PC, although not always the best way.

Comment: I'll try something around this, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following macro is a portable (between xtensa core configurations) way to load full 32-bit runtime address of the label `label` into the register `ar`:

```
.macro  get_runtime_addr label, ar, at
        .ifgt 0x\ar - 0xa0
        mov     \at, a0
        .endif
        .begin  no-transform
        _call0  1f
\label:
        .end    no-transform
        .align  4
1:
        .ifgt 0x\ar - 0xa0
        mov     \ar, a0
        mov     a0, \at
        .endif
.endm
```

The `no-transform` block around the call and the following label ensures that no literal pool or jump trampoline is inserted between them.

When the macro is used with `ar` other than `a0` it preserves the current `a0` value in the temporary register `at`. When `ar` is `a0` the argument `at` is not used and may be omitted.

Comment: Why not just have the macro return in `a0`, and let the caller use extra `mov` instructions to deal with that only if necessary?  If they actually want to add PC to something, in a non-leaf function that was already saving its incoming return address, this has three wasted `mov` instructions.

Comment: I'd expect that windowed ABI is more widespread than call0 ABI in the xtensa world, and users of windowed ABI never need to save a0 in non-leaf functions because it's done automatically by window rotation mechanism. But I think that this macro can be rewritten so that when `ar` is `a0` it doesn't do its save/restore steps.

Comment: Ok, I don't know xtensa, but I'm aware of ISAs like SPARC that have a sliding window of registers.  Regardless, I'd think you'd want to keep the macro as lightweight as possible, especially if you're going to use it all over the place for PIC code.  Just do the minimum required, leave it up to the "caller" to deal with the fact that it writes the result to `a0`.  Especially if it's efficiently possible to return with the return address in a different register, not necessarily needing it back in a0.

Comment: Making it efficient when the caller chooses `a0` is good, but it somewhat obscures the fact that choosing any other register will suddenly make the macro less efficient.  And that `\at` isn't clobbered if `\ar` is `a0`.  I guess that's somewhat a matter of coding style.  Maybe a name like `get_PC_prefer_a0` would be a useful reminder, or maybe that's just confusing.  Maybe 2 macros, one that's the raw operation, and one that can take an alternate destination and needs a temporary.  (xtensa doesn't have an exchange, does it?  That would let you use the output reg as the temporary.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this :

```
    .file   "getpc.S"
    .text
.Ltext0:
    .section    .text.get_pc,"ax",@progbits
    .align  4
    .global called_routine
    .type   called_routine, @function

// All this mess to get the PC (roughly) !

// This routine is called just to get the caller return address
// it is stored into the a0 register
called_routine:    
    entry   a1, 32
    mov     a2,a0
    retw.n


// This routine obtains something which contains 30 bits of the PC
// Please refer the xtensa instruction set manual (CALL8) for more information
// on how to rebuild the topmost 2 bits of it
    .align  4
    .global get_pc
    .global get_pc_return_address
    .type   get_pc, @function
get_pc:
    entry   a1, 32

    call8   called_routine
get_pc_return_address:
    mov.n   a2, a10
    retw.n
```